# How to download Ubuntu without installing?

Tags: downloads, iso

I have a very simple question, can I download Ubuntu without installing it?

I want to put Ubuntu onto a 4 GB memory card and install on another laptop later as the other laptop is not protected.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. You didn't say if the computer where you will download runs Windows or Ubuntu. But you need to download the Ubuntu ISO on that computer, then prepare the memory card or USB stick, and finally boot the second computer using the stick or card.

Download Ubuntu from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

See this guide on how to do it for Windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

and this one if your first computer runs Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: And sorry for my late reaction..

Comment: The desktop I want to use for the download runs Windows (7), Thanks again for all the effort! Greets Rouèl.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an USB Stick? If Yes, you can download an .iso Image from Ubuntu and then you have to put the .iso File to the USB-Stick an then you can boot and install it from the USB.

Comment: I have an ''oldschool'' Sandisk 4GB memorycard.. Thanks for the info and sorry for my late reaction..!  Greets.